# Spring boot beans order

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i'm trying to configure a spring boot project with a jetty EmbeddedContainerServlet and jndi datasource, the code below

```
@Configuration
public class EmbeddedJettyServer {

  @Value("${jetty.http.port:8080}")
  private Integer port;
  @Value("${jetty.threadPool.maxThreads:200}")
  private String maxThreads;
  @Value("${jetty.threadPool.minThreads:8}")
  private String minThreads;
  @Value("${jetty.threadPool.idleTimeout:60000}")
  private Integer idleTimeout;

private JettyServerCustomizer jettyServerCustomizer() {
    return new JettyServerCustomizer() {

        @Override
        public void customize(Server server) {
            try {
                // Tweak the connection pool used by Jetty to handle
                // incoming HTTP connections
                final QueuedThreadPool threadPool = new QueuedThreadPool();
                threadPool.setMaxThreads(Integer.valueOf(maxThreads));
                threadPool.setMinThreads(Integer.valueOf(minThreads));
                server.getBeans().add(threadPool);
                WebAppContext webAppContext = (WebAppContext) server.getHandler();
                createConfiguration(
                    "/Users/kewnen/git/zeus-info-provider/zeus-info-provider-web/ops/resources/jetty-datasource.xml")
                        .configure(webAppContext);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        private XmlConfiguration createConfiguration(String xml) throws IOException, SAXException {
            return new XmlConfiguration(new FileInputStream(xml));
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
    final JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory = new JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected JettyEmbeddedServletContainer getJettyEmbeddedServletContainer(Server server) {
            return new JettyEmbeddedServletContainer(server);
        }
    };
    jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.addServerCustomizers(jettyServerCustomizer());
    jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.setPort(port);
    jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.setSessionTimeout(idleTimeout);
    return jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
}
```

}

The content of jetty-datasource.xml file where i define the datasource stuff

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
     <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>

      <New id="cf" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
         <Arg>jdbc/zeus-info</Arg>
         <Arg>
             <New class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
            <Set name="driverClassName">org.postgresql.Driver</Set>
            <Set name="url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/myDb</Set>
            <Set name="username">postgres</Set>
            <Set name="password">password</Set>
            <Set name="validationQuery">SELECT 1</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
```

and then i define a datasource with the code below

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    return dsLookup.getDataSource("jdbc/zeus-info");
}
```

When i run it, i got this exception

```
  Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name 'jdbc/zeus-info'
at     org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot.lookup(localContextRoot.java:490)
at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot.lookup(localContextRoot.java:536)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:155)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179)
at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:104)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup.getDataSource(JndiDataSourceLookup.java:45)
```

when debuggin i see clearly the Datasource bean instantiate before the definition of the JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory where i define my jndi datasource,

i tried to force the order by adding @DependsOn annotation to the datasource definition but doesn't work, it always instantiate the DataSource bean before the container,

**Edit:**

to give more details,

i already test it by defining datasource without using jndi this way and works fine:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(DRIVER_CLASS_NAME);
    dataSource.setUrl(URL);
    dataSource.setUsername(USER);
    dataSource.setPassword(PASS);
    return dataSource;
}
```

but as its a migration from classique war with datasource defined by jndi to spring boot jar packaging project, i want to reproduce the same from existing project, cause i dont know the impact of changing jndi way to this one.

I tried to force datasource to be instanciated after container by adding this line on datasource definition

```
 @DependsOn("jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory")
```

but always instanciate the Datasource before the jetty container

**Fix :**

the problem was that spring-boot configure automatically a container with this name jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory, thats why 
@DependsOn("jettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory") didn't work,

i add

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class)
```

to my app and now it works

appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Boot properties to initialize data source bean instead of JNDI:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.type=org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/myDb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1
```

**Reaction on comment:**

So your dev environment should be as close Prod as possible. Therefore I woudln't use embedded container and rather use standalone one for development. For CI build youcan use 
maven-jetty-plugin or [Gradle Jetty plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jetty_plugin.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i edit my comment to add more details, the idea is to use the jetty xml files used in our production environnement to reproduce the same in my embedded container, thats why i try to make it with jndi

Comment: why you dont recommand the use of embedded container, is there any reason?

Comment: Because you are using WAR deployment in production. You want to develop on environment as close to production as possible.

Comment: i found why it's instantiate the datasource before, but doesn't fixe my problem... i edit my comment

Comment: the need is change war packaging to jar packaging with spring boot, using an approach of independent micro service, so we'll give the exploite team jars corresponding of each micro service, but i should reproduce the same jetty config from production environment

Comment: If you are migrating to Spring Boot with embedded Jetty, you should drop any JNDI stuff also. So my first suggestion is relevant. Keeping legacy baggage around is not good idea from my point of view.

Comment: i agree with you, but could you give me a reason to not keeping the JNDI stuff? i may need arguments to explain to the team why i would not keep it

Comment: Because Spring Boot is very opinionated. Following its defaults will make your life easier and more productive. So I would flip the question: Why not to use Spring Boot defaults? Is there any practical reason? If not, just use defaults and your testing problem will be gone.